# API Call in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to change the state of the market

Method:

```
 publishSample = () => {
    this.Service
      .publish()
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: true,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

My Component:

```
            {loading ? (
              <div>{ENUM.PUBLISH}</div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <p> {ENUM.CREATE}</p>
              </div>
            )}
```

In my above code, I want to set the value to "PUBLISH" whenever I am doing an API call & loading is true. I am able to do that but whenever I am navigating to other page (even without refreshing), instead of PUBLISH, I am getting value as "CREATE". I want to save the state as PUBLISH whenever I do a API call and want it to keep it "PUBLISH" throughout the app lifecycle. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: It should be `{this.state.loading ? ...}` instead of `{loading ?...}` no ?

Comment: i am declaring const {loading} = this.state in the render method

Comment: publishSample is getting called properly. Above code is working fine. What i want is to whenever there is an API call and the loading gets TRUE, i should get the "PUBLISH" throughout the app lifecycle

Comment: In your `then()` you are  setting `loading: true`. Should it be set to `false`? You'd need to move `loading:true` up a bit higher in the method...

Comment: Can you please share the code for second component as well? Seems like redux is best suited for this.

Comment: Can you plz help me with how to save the value in Redux?

Comment: What is the best approach to save the state to the publish throughout the app, once there is an API call?

Comment: You should use react-query for that. Its the exact fit for your use case.

Comment: @Domino987 Can you help me with how to implement react-query here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query) for that, since that is server state and should not be saved to redux, which should be used for client state only.

All your api calls, which return data, would be wrapped in a [useQuery hook](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query#queries), which will automatically refetch,  cache, sync and keep the state up to date. It also prevents multiple api calls if the same data is needed.

To display the loading state, the useQuery returns a status which can be used to show a local loading state for that query, or you can use the [useIsFetching](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query#useisfetching) hook, to show if any query is currently fetching.

This will persist over the components lifeycles, so navigating will work for that too.

To call an endpoint with data to change something, use the useMutation hook:

```
const [publishSample , { status, error }] = useMutation(this.Service.publish)

 {status === 'loading'? (
       <div>{ENUM.PUBLISH}</div>
        ) : (
         <div>
           <p> {ENUM.CREATE}</p>
         </div>
      )}
```